# API or command to check if "Fast user switching" enabled on XP

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am working on a installer, it should check FUS (Fast user switching) is enabled or not on the XP system. If FUS is enabled then installer should exit, otherwise perform the actual installation. My question is there any command line utility (or API) to check if FUS is enabled on XP?

Thanks..

Comment: Why would you do this? It's installers like this that give Windows a bad name.

Comment: @AlBlue: I agree, but I think that such installers give _themselves_ a bad name, not Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vast majority of your users (assuming an average target market) will have Fast User Switching enabled, and will not know how to disable it and possibly not want to either.  By doing this, you will annoy your customers and eliminate a large potential target market.

Why do you want to do this in the first place?

To do it, check the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AllowMultipleTSSessions`.

If FUS is enabled, it will equal 1.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My purpose not to disable the FUS. If FUS is enabled then installer will prompt a message to the user that the application won't work with FUS enabled then quits.

Comment: The purpose is one of our Authentication mode adds our customized ginaDLL and it causing the FUS option in control panel to be grayed out. There is no way to disable FUS for the user. So we would like to check if FUS is enabled or not before installing our product.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is disabled once the machine is joined to a domain (not sure if this can be overriden), so you may want to check that in addition to the registry key mentioned by SLaks.

Comment: You are correct, and it cannot be overriden.  However, it should be reflected in that registry key.

Comment: My purpose is read AllowMultipleTSSessions value only to know if FUS is enable dot not. So I think I am okay.